# lomdus and halachah-theory

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Is there a difference between the [lomdus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lomdus) and [halachah-theory](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halachah-theory) tags? If so, what is it? As far as I can tell by browsing the list of questions tagged with each, they seem pretty similar.

Comment: not all lomdus involves halacha?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, true, good point. But if the tags are otherwise identical, then the question is whether we need a separate one just for questions on _lomdus_ about _halacha_.

Comment: +1 on the question, but please do not interpret that as an endorsement for eliminating one or merging the two. I agree with [Double AA's answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/678/5), at least as far as there being merit to having both.

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference is that [lomdus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lomdus) relates to questions about the theory of Talmud study or general Talmudic concepts, while [halacha-theory](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-theory) relates to questions about theoretical issues about psak and general halacha concepts.

For instance, [What is a hakira?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/what-is-a-hakira) and [Eating outside of a Sukkah - Negative or Positive commandment?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10726/eating-outside-of-a-sukkah-lo-thaaseh-or-bittul-aseh) are about [lomdus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lomdus) and [Yerushalmi Versus Bavli in Halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/yerushalmi-versus-bavli-in-halacha), [Halachic authority of books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10330/halachic-authority-of-books) and [What is the meaning of psak?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10147/what-is-the-meaning-of-psak) are [halacha-theory](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-theory). Also note that [Is the Mitzva of Tzitzit on the Gevra or the Cheftza?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/is-the-mitzva-of-tzitzit-on-the-gevra-or-the-cheftza) is probably both.

I don't gurantee that all the current questions are tagged according to my scheme, but this is how I view it and use it.

EDIT:
I think the fact that people don't use the [lomdus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lomdus) tag very much is because they are not familiar with the word. Someone should edit in a wiki-summary and maybe we should find a good English word (I don't think "casuistry" is much clearer) to hyphen into the title of the tag.

Comment: +1 for "people don't use lombud because they don't know the word".  That certainly applies to me (and even after reading this I don't really get it).  Also, unless a tag is already in use (widespread or recent), even people who know the word might not think to generate it when typing tags.  Tags are very "flat"; maybe we need a guide to tags that groups them and breaks down hierarchies where such exist.

Comment: Double AA and @MonicaCellio, there are only 7 questions tagged "lomdus". I don't know if it is entirely because people don't know what the word means so much as people (*raises hand*) don't realize such a tag exists. I also am not entirely sure I agree with your scheme, but I would have probably used the tag on one or two questions had it occurred to me.

Comment: @SethJ It's never too late to edit :)

Comment: @SethJ or DoubleAA: could one of you populate the wiki for the tag?  That won't help with people spontaneously generating it (as already noted), but it would at least start to educate people about it (when the tag shows up and you hover over it to see what it is).  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking with regards the tzitzit question. Now it seems to me to be only [tag:lomdus].